# How can I rewrite this query to use it with query builder

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to query data from DB using typeorm. How can I make the same query using queryBuilder?

```
 const data = await this.dataRepository.findOne({
      where: [
        { field1: input1, field2: input2 },
        { field1: input2, field2: input1 }
      ]
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[By using a complex `where` clause using `Brackets`](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/select-query-builder#adding-where-expression)

```js
import { Brackets } from "typeorm"

const data = await this.dataRepository(Data) // Data refers to your Entity Class
  .createQueryBuilder("data")
  .where(new Brackets(qb => {
    qb.where("data.field1 = :field1", { field1: 'input1' })
      .andWhere("data.field2 = :field2", { field2: "input2" })
  }))
  .orWhere(new Brackets(qb => {
    qb.where("data.field1 = :field1", { field1: 'input2' })
      .andWhere("data.field2 = :field2", { field2: "input1" })
  }))
  .getOne();
```